# Twice a bridesmaid, never a bride?

Tags: folklore, superstition

I was reading Lafcadio Hearn's [New Orleans Superstitions](http://www.sacred-texts.com/afr/hearn/nos.htm), when I came upon this proverb:

> There are many superstitions about marriage, which seem to have a European origin, but are not less interesting on that account. "Twice a bridesmaid, never a bride," is a proverb which needs no comment.

Is there a vodun, voodoo or even European story behind the superstition?

Comment: FWIW, in the English oral tradition I have only ever heard "three times a bridesmaid, never a bride", never twice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I gather, the origin is uncertain, but it seems common sense that "if association with a bride and the high profile of the day did not attract a husband after two opportunities, then perhaps there was little hope" ([*Marriage Customs of the World* 98](https://books.google.com/books?id=avDXAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA98#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

In terms of pinpointing the locale of the superstition, I believe that the modern use of bridesmaids -- in the sense that they appear alongside the bride at the time of wedding -- stems perhaps from Biblical origins, at least [if you believe Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridesmaid#Origin_and_history), and so it makes sense that this superstition would crop up in Europe.

Further research is needed.

Comment: +1 for sources, and for  "further research is needed" :)